Faces and Vertex not moving in edit mode (despite being selected)
I have been using Blender 4.2. I came across an issue with my model whereby I tried to move the mesh in edit mode. However, when I press (A) and move the mesh, some vertex and face do not then to move along with the mesh and stay invariant. There are no shape keys within the mesh; I have tried merge by distance; and the mesh is not weight painted.
Is there a way of recorrecting this.
Thanks.
Original Mesh


Mesh When selected and moved in edit mode

Thanks for the advice
Harry McKenzie
♦
here is the screenshot of the original mesh

and the screenshot of the mesh when it's moved in edit mode

I have also tried your alt H suggestion, but nothing happens

Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Have you tried pressing Alt+H in Edit Mode to unhide vertices and then A move mesh.
